# How to detect web page zoom inside a flex application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I've got the following problem.
I have a flex application on a web page. In the application there is a drag-and-drop functionality with the following code to create drag thumbnails:

```
// this is a part of drag event listener in a flex control
    var thumbnail_copy:Image = new Image();
    thumbnail_copy.load(some_url);
    thumbnail_copy.width = 50;
    thumbnail_copy.height = 50;

    DragManager.doDrag(drag_initiator, drag_source, event, thumbnail_copy);
```

But if I zoom the web page, the size of the drag thumbnail increases. It's incorrect.

So how can I fix the bug? I suppose I need something like a web zoom factor inside my application to compensate zooming.

Comment: Hmm. Would this be a case to take a look at the stage.scaleMode? At least it is impossible to read the zoom level of the browser directly. Even if it would be in one of the standards, the browser agent would even then most likely respect the user's privacy instead.